# Сделать django админку удобней

Tags: django, django-admin

В проекте стало настолько много апликух и моделей что админка без скролла не влазит на большой монитор. Да и искать в этой куче нужную модель уже крайне  сложно. Какие есть возможности (желательно встроенных в django, но боюсь их нет, так что можно и внешних апликух) **сделать админку сгруппированей, удобней, юзабельней и гибче**? Интересует больше первая страница навигации.

*ПС использую grappelli, может в нем есть что-то чего я не заметил.*

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: Я не раз читал документацию, правда у меня версия 1.3. В 1.4 появилось что-то, что позволяет поменять первую страницу админки - навигацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно вам придется переписать сам шаблон. Но можете еще посмотреть на этот проект [django-admin-tools](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: хотелось бы совета от тех кто пытался решить подобную задачу, почему именно этот проект?

Answer (score 1):

вот тут приложения можно группировать и скрывать не нужные. главная странциа (дашборд) кастомизируется под нужны
https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet

Answer (score 1):

Я использую [djangosuit.com](http://djangosuit.com/).

Есть боковое меню, закладки и т.д. посмотрите [DEMO](http://djangosuit.com/admin/)